# jQuery Find and Replace is Hanging up the browser! Data size too big?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

With alot of help from @kalley we have found out that If I comment the following two lines out the LAG is gone!

```
 var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody')
 var $html = $('<tbody/>').html(data);
```

---

***But how do I keep the above but cancel out the LAG ?***

---

**MORE INFO:**
The code below works but the problem is that the `$.GET` is causing the browser to hang until the ajax request completes. I need (flow control?) or something that will solve this problem without locking/hanging up the browser until ajax completes the GET request.

The biggest LAG/Lockup/Hang is at `$.get("updatetable.php"`, since the others only return 7 or less (number) values and this one ('updatetable.php') returns alot more (200-300kb). I would like to implement some sort of flow control here or make the script wait like 5 secs before firing the update command for tablesort and before showing the toast message so that ajax has time to GET the `$.get("updatetable.php"`data I just don't understand why does it lockup the browser as it is getting the data? is it trying to fire the other commands and that's whats causing the LAG?

**Here are the STEPS**

**1.**
`$.get("getlastupdate.php"` Will fire every 10 secs or so to check if the date and time are the same the return data looks like this: `20130812092636` the format is: YYYmmddHHmmss.

**2.**
if the date and time are not the same as the last GET then `$.get("getlastupdate2.php"` will trigger and this data will be send back and placed into a toast message and dispalyed to the user `$().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', Vinfoo`);

**3.**
before or after the above (`$.get("getlastupdate2.php"`) another GET will fire:  `$.get('updatetable.php'` this will GET the updated table info. and replace the old one with the new info. and then update/resort the table

**4.**
at the end of it all I want to `$.get("ajaxcontrol.php"` and this will return a 1 or 2 if the user is logged in then it will be a 2 else it's a 1 and it will destroy the session and log the user out.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/final/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/final/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/final/toastmessage/jquery.toastmessage-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var comper;
    function checkSession() {
        return $.get("ajaxcontrol.php", function (DblIn) {
            console.log('checking for session');
            if (DblIn == 1) {
                window.location = 'loggedout.php';
            }
        }).then(updateTable);
    }

    function checkComper() {
        var SvInfo;
        var onResponse = function (comperNow) {
            if (comper === undefined) {
                comper = comperNow;
            } else if (comper !== comperNow) {
                var Vinfoo;
                comper = comperNow;
                // returning this $.get will make delay done until this is done.
                return $.get("getlastupdate2.php", function (primaryAddType) {
                    Vinfoo = primaryAddType;
                    $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', Vinfoo);
                }).then(checkSession);
            }
        };
        $.get('getlastupdate.php').then(onResponse).done(function () {
            tid = setTimeout(checkComper, 2000);
        });
    }


    function updateTable() {
        return $.get('updatetable.php', function (data) {
            console.log('update table');
var $table = $("table.tablesorter");
            var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody')
            var $html = $('<tbody/>').html(data);
              $tableContents.replaceWith('<tbody>' + data + '</tbody>')
            //$tableContents.replaceWith($html)
            $table.trigger("update", [true]);
            var currentUrl = document.getElementById("frmcontent").contentWindow.location.href;
            var urls = ['indexTOM.php', 'index1.php'],
                frame = document.getElementById('frmcontent').contentDocument;

            for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                var url = urls[i];
                if (frame.location.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                    frame.location.reload()
                }
            }

            $('[title!=""]').qtip({});
        });

    };


    $(function () {
    var tid = setTimeout(checkComper, 2000);


    $("#append").click(function (e) {
        // We will assume this is a user action
        e.preventDefault();
        updateTable();
    });

            // call the tablesorter plugin
            $("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
                theme: 'blue',
                // hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize the change
                widthFixed: true,
                // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
                widgets: ["saveSort", "zebra", "filter"],
                headers: {
                    8: {
                        sorter: false,
                        filter: false
                    }
                },
                widgetOptions: {
                    filter_childRows: false,
                    filter_columnFilters: true,
                    filter_cssFilter: 'tablesorter-filter',
                    filter_filteredRow: 'filtered',
                    filter_formatter: null,
                    filter_functions: null,
                    filter_hideFilters: false, // true, (see note in the options section above)
                    filter_ignoreCase: true,
                    filter_liveSearch: true,
                    filter_reset: 'button.reset',
                    filter_searchDelay: 300,
                    filter_serversideFiltering: false,
                    filter_startsWith: false,
                    filter_useParsedData: false
                }
            });

            // External search
            $('button.search').click(function () {
                var filters = [],
                    col = $(this).data('filter-column'), // zero-based index
                    txt = $(this).data('filter-text'); // text to add to filter
                filters[col] = txt;
                $.tablesorter.setFilters($('table.hasFilters'), filters, true); // new v2.9
                return false;
            });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you using `asnyc: false`? Aside from that I don't know, your code is completely unreadable.

Comment: Yea .. so don't use it?

Comment: I'm not and it's still the same. it takes alil more time for the $.get("getlastupdate2.php" to get all the data back and this is what is causing the hang, I want it to control the flow so that it doesn't lockup/hang

Comment: Are your Ajax replies very large? ie. does the browser spend a lot of time parsing?

Comment: First, never place an ajax call inside a setInterval unless it is async: false. if the request takes longer than the interval to complete, it could eventually crash the browser.

Comment: @KevinB If you use async: false that will lockup the browser until the ajax request is done so it's a problem within a problem.

Comment: @msvuze Agreed, but it wouldn't crash the browser. I'm not suggesting using async: false, as that obviously wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: This is turning out to be an excellent question as I cannot stop thinking about it now!! (:

Comment: Your are nesting so much $(document).ready() handlers that it just makes no sense. Also, you're running your ajax every two seconds... why on earth would you do that ?

Comment: @DidierGhys Thanks for your comment, 2 sec is just a example I will update it to 10 sec the LAG is still there, I will also fix the $(document).ready(). Thanks again.

Comment: You havent fixed problem, you have $(document).ready() inside click handler inside document ready. it is obviously wrong.

Comment: @vittore I think? I got it corrected now, Thanks vittore

Comment: Break this down into smaller piece and debug individually, or use a javascript profiler (Chrome, Firefox, and IE all have nice profilers built in) to see where the execution time is really being spent.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen if async: true then I can crash the browser since I'm using setInterval and if async: false then the browser locksup

Comment: @JasonP Thanks for your help, I did as you said and the time is lost the most here $.get("getlastupdate2.php" I think that the lag happens since  $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', Vinfoo); wants to show the notice/msg but ajax didn't get the data back yet.

Comment: I'd suggest not to use `setInterval` together with Ajax. Use `setTimeout` and trigger a new timeout inside the success callback.

Comment: Try using `$.post()` while keeping all the data encoded in the URL with that request. That will essentially perform a GET request because there is no data being posted. And I've noticed in the past that jQuery only seems to allow one GET request with `$.get()` and many simultaneous POST requests with `$.post()`. Maybe it was that one version, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Would it be beneficial to check if the person should be logged out before pulling down the updated table data?

Comment: @Pluto Thanks for the $.POST :) same result :(

Comment: @kalley Yes, that would be good since it would not do the BIG updatetable.php GET so it saves on data.

Comment: Isn't this unrelated to `$.GET`? It's your javascript code that runs when the result is returned that's blocking the browser?

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: `updateTable` is defined within the scope of the `ready` handler function. (By "`ready` handler" I mean the function inside the jQuery call: `$(function () { ...`.) It is not accessible outside of that function. Move the declaration of `updateTable` outside of the `ready` handler.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for the help, but when its outside I get $table is undefined error, see updated code in my question above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of using `setInterval`, you should consider switching to `setTimeout`. It will give you more control over when the time repeats:

```
function checkComper() {
    var SvInfo;
    var onResponse = function (comperNow) {
        if (comper === undefined) {
            comper = comperNow;
        } else if (comper !== comperNow) {
            var Vinfoo;
            comper = comperNow;
            // returning this $.get will make delay done until this is done.
            return $.get("getlastupdate2.php", function (primaryAddType) {
                Vinfoo = primaryAddType;
                $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', Vinfoo);
            }).then(checkSession);
        }
    };
    $.get('getlastupdate.php').then(onResponse).done(function () {
        tid = setTimeout(checkComper, 10000);
    });
}

var tid = setTimeout(checkComper, 10000);
```

Then you can keep it `async: true`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EgJJh/6/) showing it working using echo.jsontest.com and some fudging numbers.

Since the `click` event callback seems to be where the issue is, try doing this and see if it removes the lag (I removed other comments to make it more brief):

```
function checkSession() {
    return $.get("ajaxcontrol.php", function (DblIn) {
        console.log('checking for session');
        if (DblIn == 1) {
            window.location = 'loggedout.php';
        }
    }).then(updateTable);
}
function updateTable() {
    return $.get('updatetable.php', function (data) {
        console.log('update table');
        var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody')
        //var $html = $('<tbody/>').html(data);
        //$tableContents.replaceWith($html);

        // replaceWith text seems to be much faster:
        // http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-replacewith/4
        $tableContents.replaceWith('<tbody'> + data + '</tbody>');

        //$table.trigger("update", [true]);
        var currentUrl = document.getElementById("frmcontent").contentWindow.location.href;
        var urls = ['indexTOM.php', 'index1.php'],
            frame = document.getElementById('frmcontent').contentDocument;

        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            var url = urls[i];
            if (frame.location.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                frame.location.reload()
            }
        }

        $('[title!=""]').qtip({});
    });

};

$("#append").click(function (e) {
    // We will assume this is a user action
    e.preventDefault();
    updateTable();
});
```

I commented out `$table.trigger("update", [true])` since if you sort the table on the server before you return it, you shouldn't need to run that, which I'm almost certain is where the bottleneck is.

Comment: What does the response for `getlastupdate2.php` look like? Trying to figure out what the issue would be might lie there.

Comment: it looks like this: <b><a href=address.php?id=744 style="font-family:Lucida Grange; font-size:14px; color:white;">FA Number: #2003 (John Anderson)</a></b><BR><BR>In: <font color="yellow">Billings, MT</font> - On:08-12-2013<BR><BR><i>Updated By: Mike</i>

Comment: Let me take a look at what we have there, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok the LAG is at         $("#append").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get('updatetable.php', function (data) {
The updatetable.php is html for the entire table/images/link. Is there a way to make AJAX get the updatetable.php first and once done update the table, what its doing is trying to update the table right away but it doesnt have all the data for it or that's what i think Size of updatetable.php is about 200kb-300kb

Comment: Anyway you can sort the table on the server? I think that the `update` event is what is causing the lag. See what happens when you comment that out.

Comment: I updated my answer with something that I think will work for you. You'll still be updating the table from the server via AJAX.

Comment: I tired your answer and there is still LAG. Is it possible to get the data from updatetable.php before the other commands are triggered because I'm 100% sure now that is the problem, thanks for everything.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the expected flow of those `get` requests? Like `getlastupdate2.php` -> `getlastupdate2.php` or in a list? Then I can at least help you get a chain of requests in the right order and we can see if that is indeed the bottleneck or if it's somehow related to a different part of the code.

Comment: I updated my question, see UPDATE# 2 I think that is what you wanted ? also, I can combine #1 and #4 to minimize the GET's I was thinking to add the ajaxcontrol.php value to the end of the YYYYmmddHHmmss since it's is only one value, let me know what you think, hanks.

Comment: @compcobalt Did you try the fiddle (or the updated fiddle link in the answer) in the comment above yours? I'll update my answer to include that code instead of what's there, as it makes sure there is only one request happening at a time.

Comment: Thanks for editing your code example (above) that really helped me understand better then using the fiddle. I was getting $table is undefined error, so I added var $table = $("table.tablesorter"); (see my updated code) no error all looks well but still the LAG when update table! :(

Comment: Unfortunately it might be related to the amount of data being returned. You may have to look at some sort of pagination or something... though it's never my favorite option. Is there a way to do like a difference between the current table state and what's already there?

Comment: Yup the LAG is here       //////  var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody')
      //////  var $html = $('<tbody/>').html(data);
  IF I COMMENT IT OUT THE LAG IS GONE!!

Comment: No, I have to get the entire tbody :( well wait unless I can assign something like data-id to each <TR> and then check the datetime GET every 1 sec. and if it has changed then GET the single <TR> from updatetable.php like this the size of the updatetable.php will be really small.

Comment: I think that the biggest problem is not the size of the rows since there are only about 60 total rows but the problem is that I'm taking the entire HTML source of the tbody from the 61 rows and that is making the size really big since each row is using alot of html: images, links, etc so a pager will not help here. BTW, I will award you the points since you went out of your way to help me, I wish you had a solution for me but I understand that this is free help and not a full time job. Thanks for everything Kalley I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @compcobalt I'm not sure how much more help I can be given the information. But you may want to take a look at tip #6 [here](http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/7-tips-made-rendering-html-faster-do-it-lately). You may also want to look at this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-replacewith/3). Might be better to do a `replaceWith('<tbody>' + data + '</tbody>')`. Good luck!

Comment: I checked out the links you gave me and the one at http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-replacewith/3 the middle test is the fastest "use .replaceWith() to replace the content" it's ALOT! faster but how do I add this to my script ? Is it just by doing this: $tableContents.replaceWith('<tbody>' + data + '</tbody>')

Comment: Yep. I updated my code above to reflect that (but not the fiddle). It's probably the `.html` call you have that's slowing things down since `.html` has a bunch of `table` specific checks in it. But yeah, `$tableContents.replaceWith('<tbody>' + data + '</tbody>')` should help at least a little.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard untangle the mess you have but if what you want is ajax requests every 10 seconds it make sense to separate this logic from business logic over data from server.

Your code would also really benefit from using promises. Consider this example

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     var myData = {  }
      , ajaxPromise = null


     setInterval(callServer, 1000)


     function callServer() {

        ajaxPromise = updateCall()
                       .then(controlCall)
                       .done(handler)
                       .error(errorHandler) 
     }
     function updateCall() {
       return $.get('updateTable.php', function(data) {
          myData.update = data
       })
     } 

     function controlCall( ) {
       return $.get('ajaxControl.php', function(data) {
          myData.control = data
       })
     }

     function handler() {
       console.dir(myData)
     }

     function errorHandler(err) {
        console.log(err)
        console.dir(myData)         
     }
 })
```

Comment: Misusing `when`. That's not what it is for.

Comment: @meagar I like to put it clarity of what's going on, I know it creates extra promise.

Comment: You're just promoting the misunderstanding that `when` is somehow required, that `when`/`then` always go together.