# Trying to understand $.get, $.when and $.then

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to understand `$.when(...).then(...).done(...)`. This is just tests.

Html:

```
<p id="phrase"></p>
<button id="btn">get phrase</button>
```

javascript:

```
var p = $('#phrase');

function displayResult(o){
    console.log(o);
    p.append(o + ' ');
};

function getSubject(){
    console.log('getSubject');
    return $.get(
    'sujet.js', //returns "the quick brown fox"
    displayResult
    );
}

function getVerb(){
    console.log('getVerb');
    return $.get(
    'verbe.js',//returns "jumps over"
    displayResult
    );  
}

function getComplement(){
    console.log('getComplement');
    return $.get(
    'complement.js', //returns "the lazy dog"
    displayResult
    );
}

function close(){
    p.append("!!!");
}

function load(){
    $.when(getSubject())
    .then(getVerb)
    .then(getComplement)
    .done(close);
}

$('#btn').click(load);
```

As I understand it, it should:

1. request for `sujet.js`, display the string in the paragraph.
2. request for `verbe.js`, display the string in the paragraph.
3. request for `complement.js`, display the string in the paragraph.
4. append "!!!" to the paragraph.

All it does is getting `sujet.js`. `displayResult` is never called, neither the functions passed to `then` and `done`.

So, I probably misunderstood something.

I got the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152121/607162).

**EDIT**

My problem was a parse error, not related to `$.when` or `$.then`. Once fixed, the rest worked as expected. However I marked meagar's answer as accepted because it explained well how the thing works.

Comment: add a .fail after .done and console.log the arguments.

Comment: `when` is for grouping multiple deferred objects. You don't need it here.

Comment: @Kevin: yeah, I got a parseError... thanks.

Comment: @Johnny5 And, that means your ajax request is returning data that can't be parsed by jQuery.

Comment: It's a plain text file with "The quick brown fox" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.when(...).then(...).done(...)` isn't a thing, in the sense that you don't *need* `when`, and you don't need `then`, and you don't need to terminate the chain with `done`. Just chain your promise-returning functions together with `then`, and add a `fail` handler:

```
getSubject()
.then(getVerb)
.then(getComplement)
.then(close)
.fail(function () {
  console.log("One of the functions failed");
});
```

Note that by omitting a `fail` you're basically missing the whole benefit of using deferreds over success/failure callbacks: "catching" failure from any level with one unified error handling method.

Comment: Nice for "I dont need when", but do I understand it right if I say that the `getVerb` will be executed _only_ when the ajax request of `getSubject` will complete, and so on for `getComplement` and `close` ?

Comment: Yes. Each subsequent function is being passed as a callback to the success handler of the previous deferred. Because we're using `then`, the returned promise of each success handler "becomes" the new promise, for the next `then` in the chain.

Comment: @Johnny5 Note that, if each task is not dependent on the previous task, you *can* use `when`: `$.when(getSubject(), getVerb(), getComplement()).then(close).done(...).fail(...)`.

Comment: To add to meagar's comments.  As of jQuery 1.8, `.then()` has become a replacement for `.pipe()`... but only sometimes.  For this reason, I believe you shouldn't use it.  If any of the function's inside `.then()` return a value, the return will act as a NEW deferred that additional `.done()`/`.fail()`'s will be attached to (NOT the original).  This behavior can lead to strange behavior if not understood.

Comment: Because, now, the only way to simulate `.pipe()` is to now use `.then()`, it is my personal preference to only use `.then()` as if it were `.pipe()` to avoid confusion.  Using `.then()` the way you have maps to `.done()`, so use that instead for clarity.  Use `.then()` for a sequence of tasks, `.when()` for parallel tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The `.then()` part will only be called whenever the `$.Deferred`/`promist` object returned by the previous function call either gets `resolve()`-d or `reject()`-ed. If `$.get` terminates with an error, if never gets resolved or rejected, and the function calls in `.then()` will wait forever.
Because of what you see, I am assuming that the ajax call `$.get` in function `getSubject()` terminates in an abnormal way.
To see if that is the case, simly add a `.fail()` handler to your function chain:

```
$.when(getSubject())
    .then(getVerb)
    .then(getComplement)
    .done(close)
    .fail() {
         console.log('An error occured.');
    });
```

Comment: When you obmit the `dataType` parameter in the `$.ajax` call in jquery (where `$.get` is a shorthand for that with certain parameters set to default values), it'll do an *intelligent guess* on the data type that is returned. In my experience, that guess is not so intelligent. It's best to tell the ajax call what the server will return, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this way too. It will help tell where along the way one of the functions is failing:

```
function getSubject(){
    console.log('getSubject');
    return $.get(
       'sujet.js', //returns "the quick brown fox"
       displayResult
    ).done(function() { console.log("subject failed"); });
}
```

Similar for the other ones.

Comment: @KevinB Dumb of me. Whole new answer.